# How to load balance url request to a dedicated weblogic node?

Tags: weblogic, load-balancing, cluster-computing

For some performance issue, i need to process one kind of request in a dedicated node. For example, I need to process all request like `http://hostname/report*` on node1. So, I added a rule in load balancer to redirect `http://hostname/report*` to `http://node1name/report*`. But node1 ask me to login again. And I was logged in `http://hostname/ already`. How can I directly access without login again?

Comment: So your sessions are not replicated across the cluster? You will need some kind of single sign-on solution

Answer (score 0):

As @JoseK mentioned, it looks like you don't have session replication and failover configured between the servers. You will need all of your application servers to be inside the same WebLogic cluster and you will also have to pick their secondary session replication node to be the destination for in-memory replication. You can dictate this by assigning the dedicated node to a specific machine, which is then selected as the secondary replication target for all cluster members.

Also, for session replication to work, all objects within your session have to be/implement serializable.